# Hyperlink from database appears in wrong content holder

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

This is a really odd bug and for the life of me i can't figure out why.
I have a website divided to 3 content holders: an horizontal menu above , vertical menu on the right and main content holder.

The right menu is generated from a sql database using a asp.net Repeater like this:

```
 <div id="scroller" style="width:290px; height:250px; overflow:hidden;">

       <asp:Repeater ID="MatRep" runat="server">

           <HeaderTemplate> <ul style="list-style-type:none;"> </HeaderTemplate>

           <ItemTemplate> <li style="margin-top:10px;"> <h3 style="text-align:center;"> <a href="/MaterialsGate.aspx?try=<%#Eval("Cataloged Number")%>"> <%#Eval("Material Name")%>  </h3> </li></ItemTemplate>

           <FooterTemplate> </ul> </FooterTemplate>

       </asp:Repeater>     

        </div>
```

The function of the right menu is that when a link is clicked it sends an ID to the next page and then i can see on the main content what was clicked.

**The problem is that the last link of the menu goes out of the right column and into the main content for some reason.**
That means that if i clicked on the center of the screen , no way near the last hyperlink of the right menu - it will act as i clicked that same hyperlink.

Any idea why would this happen?

If any more code snippets are needed i'll be glad to supply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try closing anchor tag , and change " by ' on href attribute

```
 <li style="margin-top:10px;"> 
     <h3 style="text-align:center;"> 
         <a href='/MaterialsGate.aspx?try=<%#Eval("Cataloged Number")%>' > <!-- HERE -->
           <%#Eval("Material Name")%>   
         </a>  <!-- HERE -->
      </h3> 
  </li>
```

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for the response.
I first tried replacing the " with ' but no luck there.
I'm not sure i understand whats the meaning of a closing anchor tag - do you mean just add "/a"?
wouldn't that cancel the hyperlink completely?

Comment: Oh got it! i added <a> </a> in the footer template and it totally worked. thanks Mate!

Comment: Great! In these cases always look at the HTML rendering in the browser (right click and "view source") and check if it is generated correctly.